# On groups with none of their quotient groups divisible

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Does there exist a group $G$ that satisfies the following conditions:

- Any proper subgroup of $G$ is contained in a maximal subgroup.
- There is some $N\unlhd G$ such that $\frac{G}{N}$ is [*divisible*](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Divisible_group).

?

How about if $G$ is abelian?

My definition of divisibility is the same as what is used in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/419101/138171

Comment: trying to find a counterexample?

Comment: What is it that makes you think it is false?

Comment: If second condition is not satisfied, the first one is satisfied. I'm asking for the converse.

Answer (score 3):

There does not exist an abelian group with the prescribed properties.

Assume contrariwise that $G$ is such a group and that $N\lhd G$ gives rise to a divisible quotient group. The first assumption implies that $N$ is contained in a maximal subgroup $M$. If $G/M$ is infinite, then it has non-trivial subgroups, so correpondence principle tells us that there are subgroups properly between $M$ and $G$. So $G/M$ is finite, say $n=[G:M]$.

This implies that for all $x\in G$ we have $x^n=M$. So if $yN\in G/N$ is chosen in such a way that $y\notin M$, then $(zN)^n\neq yN$ for all $z\in G$, because $(zN)^n\in M/N$.

---

If we look for a non-abelian example, the same argument does not work, because $M$ is not necessarily normal. The argument only disallows those pairs $(G,N)$ such that $N$ is contained in a normal subgroup of a finite index.

Comment: if $x\in G$, then $Mx^n=M$ so $x^n\in M$.

Comment: There is some $y\in G\setminus M$. for any $z\in G$, if $Nz^n=Ny$ then $yz^{-n}\in N\subseteq M$ and so $My=Mz^n=M$ which implies $y\in M$. So $Nz^n\ne Ny$.

Comment: So the equation $\theta ^n = yN$ has no solution for $\theta$ in $G\over N$ which is a contradiction because $G\over N$ is divisible by hypothesis. thanks. I could accept this answer if the group was assumed to be abelian.

Comment: A subgroup of index $n$ contains a normal subgroup of index $\le n!$, so in such a group $G$ there has to be a maximal subgroup of infinite index.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this proposition?

Comment: @user It is a standard result: act on the cosets of your subgroup by left multiplication, and take the kernel of this action.